# MQTT client variable certificate strings

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

In order to deploy an MQTT client on multiple devices with multiple certificates, I don't want to change the strings manually.

```
PATH_TO_CERT = "certs/{some-value}-device.pem.crt"
PATH_TO_KEY = "certs/{some-value}-private.pem.key"
PATH_TO_ROOT = "certs/root.pem"
```

This is how the basic structure looks like. The ending of the device crt and the private key always look the same. Is there way to define a 'wildcard' do I can just copy the new certificates and my code will pick the right certificates regardless of the 'some-value', which is different for each device?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: Or setup a symlink on to a generic name that points to the hostname specific name?

Comment: glob can be working since it will ultimately run on Ubuntu. For testing purposes, it will run on windows, so the glob patterns won't work for now.

Comment: Never used it but [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) should work on both Windows and Unix.

Comment: OK, figured it out. I used ```certs = os.listdir('certs/')``` and since I got the same structure of files, I can just give the string a list item like: ```PATH_TO_CERT = "certs/" + certs[0]```